# Memory Leak happening when using static instance of GsonBuilder to create Gson instances

Tags: java, memory-leaks, static, gson

I am using Google's excellent Gson library for doing JSON (de)serialization. I am making use of the `GsonBuilder` class to create `Gson` objects with custom serializers for certain classes. At a later point after the code was deployed, I suddenly started getting Heap Overflow errors.

I studied the heap dump and it pointed to the `static final` object of the `GsonBuilder` class:

```
public static final GsonBuilder JSONIFIER_BUILDER = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Article.class, new ArticleSerializer());
```

To create a `Gson` object from the builder, I have a method which is being used by multiple apps in my code.

```
public String serialize(Object contextObject) {
    Gson jsonifier = JSONIFIER_BUILDER.registerTypeAdapter(Config.class, new ConfigSerializer(contextObject)).create();
    return jsonifier.toJson(this);
}
```

From looking at the heap dump I could only infer that the `JSONIFIER_BUILDER` somehow has reference to all the instances of `Gson` object it creates.

Can someone tell me if I am making a correct conclusion? If so, how could I have avoided this problem?  I have currently made changes to the code so that the serializer method could look like this:

```
public String serialize(Object contextObject) {
    Gson jsonifier = new GsonBuilder()
                                .registerTypeAdapter(Article.class, new ArticleSerializer()).registerTypeAdapter(Config.class, new ConfigSerializer(contextObject)).create();
        return jsonifier.toJson(this);
}
```

Comment: What is that keyword `final` in there?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen looks like the migration of the question did not happen properly. This is a java question.

Answer (score 2):

```
public String serialize(Object contextObject) {
   Gson jsonifier = JSONIFIER_BUILDER.registerTypeAdapter(Config.class, new ConfigSerializer(contextObject)).create();
   return jsonifier.toJson(this);
}
```

You keep registering new types to your static builder. Which it apparently does not overwrite the previous one.

[GsonBuilder source](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.java)

Comment: yeah, I want to add on more type adapters, in addition to the existing one. & then yse the current state of JSON builder to create a new `Gson`. But I would have thought that addition of type adapters would just overwrite the existing (if any) of the same class.

Comment: I agree I thought it would do that too but I checked the source and it clearly doesn't.

Comment: Hmm. This line https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.java#452 actually suggests that it would be overwritten, and they themselves say that it should  be overwritten in ther code documentation.

Comment: Only if ConfigSerializer implements `InstanceCreator` I had assumed it implemented `JsonSerializer` or `JsonDeserializer` due to the name.

Comment: FYI I have opened a bug in google-gson forum for this at https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=584&thanks=584&ts=1406558605

Comment: But @Sign this still does not explain why the references to `Gson` instances created from this builder are still maintained by the builder.

Comment: @Chantz I would assume you were reading the heap dump incorrectly. Not sure how to read a heap dump myself so I can't offer any advice.

Comment: @Chantz how did you resolve this issue? Could you please provide some details? Thanks.

Comment: @DoIt don't remember at this point. It's been 5 years now and I don't have access to the repo as well. Sorry! Probably gson fixed this issue?